# Adding 2 Images dynamically in the bottom

Tags: android, dynamic, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get 2 images attached to layout bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118457/how-to-get-2-images-attached-2-layout-botton)

I want to attach 2 images 1st at left bottom corner and other on right bottom corner but I want that images to be hardcore in bottom so that if I scroll the page the images should remain at the same place But the maine thing is I want all of it dynamically not by xml

Comment: Have u tried anything? This seems relatively easy. We are happy to help if you ran into any problem while trying.

Comment: @paresh now dis ty, u should b clear its written dynamically how can it b same ?

Comment: @ph7 i have tried raltive layout but it is possible for single image which i cn place in left bottom corner but  dont knw about the second

Comment: @PareshMayani i want it  dynamically Sir! :)

Comment: @RaghavChopra but my dear, As per SO community FAQ you should update your existing question with one more point "Also want it to do dynamically", because this is the brand new question for your same problem. Sorry for my hactic schedule, let me try if possible i will get you out.

Comment: @PareshMayani well its so kind of u  if u help me out

Comment: @PareshMayani iwill add it from next time thanx fr ur help  :)

Comment: @PareshMayani yeaai succededd in my codee thnk u

Answer (score 0):

If you add the images outside of the portion of the layout that is scrollable, then those images won't scroll.

As for doing it dynamically, you just need to try and learn how to make dynamic layouts. I grabbed the first tutorial link after Googling "android dynamic layouts" for you: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130521-android-part-iii-dynamic-layouts/

Comment: Well i like ur tutorial but i can do that  what  yu have given me

Comment: i just want 2 images  as i have explained can u help me out .?